# Swift 3 - How do I prevent instantiated view controllers from having their background disappear behind the tab and navigation bars?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

I have a Storyboard with a Navigation controller and a connected Table View Controller.  This table has cells that, when clicked, link to custom table view controllers that I instantiate each time.

```
let detailVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dvc") as! ResultsVC
detailVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
detailVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = [];
```

But this newly created VC seems to have its background disappear behind the top nav bar and bottom tab bar because its colors change.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior (I'm assuming that you're pushing the newly-instantiated VC with your navigation controller). If your views are hidden behind the navigation bar, do one of two things: 1) change the frame of your new VC's view, so that the y coord is equal to your navigation bar's height, or 2) push the views from IB, not in code, and this will be handled for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If I do manually set up the frame's position, height and width, how do I adjust for times when the application switches to landscape view?

Comment: Implement the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation, and put any UI changes in a main queue block. Or disable landscape. Or use programatically-added constraints, instead of setting your y-value (this can be tough to do). For the record, I'd highly recommend using IB for all Navigation Controller management, but understand that there are edge cases where this can't be done.